# What Java Driver Version is being used by Goolge Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, jdbc

We have been using a JDBC connection in a Google Sheet Apps Script to connect to a hosted SQL server. This has worked well until the changes were made to the SQL server by the hosting company. The hosting company says we need to use Java Driver version 8.4. We are unable to identify what Java Driver version Google Apps Script is using and Google cannot seem to answer the question either.

Does anyone know the driver version or a way to find it?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you can get it from the JDBC connection by selecting:

```java
JdbcConnection.getMetaData().getDriverVersion(); //returns a string
```

The final link is: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/jdbc/jdbc-database-meta-data

There's also two functions, `getDriverMajor()`/`MinorVersion()`, which return integers.

I've haven't done this a lot so I don't know how dependable it is.

Comment: Thank you. I am trying to figure out how to make this function work with a jdbc connection that is not able to connect. Our Google partner got a response from Google regarding the driver version, we are trying to verify TLS version now.  Per Google, the API version is 4.3 and it uses a proprietary Microsoft JDBC drive which is version 8.4